# How to setup a GET method in AWS API Gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, get, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I want to submit a GET request using Authorization and Content-Type(`application/json`) as headers. Authorization would contain "Bearer " + token.

[image]

I am using Lambda function as to trigger when user hits this API endpoint. As this is get request, I am sending `body = undefined` in parameters.
But since 4-5 hours I am getting "internal server error" as of `status code =502`.

I noticed that these requests are due to bad gateway, still they are captured in cloudwatch logs.

The thing is, I want to know how to setup a GET request in AWS API gateway as I have not much experience in this technology.

Comment: Why do you need content type as application/json if you do not have any content in body? What is the input to your GET request?

Comment: Does the GET request hit your Lambda function?  If so, can you share your Lambda code so we may be able to assist?

Comment: When using Lambda Proxy integration, try to format your response as follows
{
        'statusCode': 200,
        'headers': { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        'body': 'Whatever'
    }

Comment: @Shetty I have that content-type in response headers.

Comment: @ParrettApps Yes it hits lambda but still it displays bad gateway error

Comment: @qkhanhpro Will do that now onwards

Comment: Note that `Bad Gateway` is a generic failure code that often, in this context, means API Gateway could not invoke or make sense of the response from the Lambda function.  Start with the logs for both Lambda and API Gateway.  Find a failed request, and edit what you found in the logs into the question, above.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Thanks for the detailed description. It works flawlessly instead I have also done serverless integration.